# Jquery change setInterval speed with mouse position

Tags: jquery, animation, cursor, mouseevent, setinterval

I would like to make an eye blink faster and faster as the mouse get closer, like this example with the heart :

[image]

with this eye (without the circle) :

[image]

I managed to make it blink but I'm still trying to change interval speed while the cursor is moving.
Here is my code :

```js
var mX, mY, distance, intervalSpeed = 500, interval,
  intervalSpeedMax = 500;
  intervalSpeedMin = 100;
  max_distance = 213,
        $distance = $('#distance'),
        $element  = $('.icone');

     function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
         return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
     }


    $(".wrapper").on('mouseenter', function(){

      interval = setInterval(function(){
       $(".first").toggle();
       $(".second").toggle();
      }, intervalSpeed);

   $(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
          mX = e.pageX;
          mY = e.pageY;
          distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
          $distance.text("distance : " + distance);

          // Calcul de l'interval
          intervalSpeed = ((intervalSpeedMax - intervalSpeedMin) * distance / max_distance ) + intervalSpeedMin;
     
      });  
       
     });
      
  
    $(".wrapper").on('mouseleave', function(){
      clearInterval(interval);
      $(".first").show();
      $(".second").hide();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  html{
   height: 100%;
  }
  body{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   min-height: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper{
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: salmon;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   position: relative;
  }
  #distance{
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   left: 5px;
  }
  .icone{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
  }
  img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
  }
  img:first-of-type{
   
  }
  img:nth-of-type(2){
   display: none;
   top: 20px;
  }

  
 </style>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="wrapper">
  <span id="distance"></span>
  <div class="icone">
   <img class="first" src="https://i.ibb.co/ysX2Hm0/Fichier-4.png">
   <img class="second" src="https://i.ibb.co/mBFRn0V/Fichier-3.png">
  </div>
 </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I confess the eye isn't perfect but that's not the point here. I can't manage to make the interval speed change smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution using setTimeOut function. I created a function "animDisplay" called when the mouse enters inside the salmon square. The delay is calculated in this function according to the mouse's position like this :

```
var mX, mY, distance, intervalSpeed = 500, interval,
    intervalSpeedMax = 500;
    intervalSpeedMin = 100;
    max_distance = 213,
    $distance = $('#distance'),
    $element  = $('.icone');

    function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
    }

    function animDisplay(){
        $(".first").toggle();
        $(".second").toggle();
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
            mX = e.x;
            mY = e.y;
        });
        distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
        intervalSpeed = ((intervalSpeedMax - intervalSpeedMin) * distance / max_distance ) + intervalSpeedMin;
        interval = setTimeout(animDisplay, intervalSpeed);
    }


   $(".wrapper").on('mouseenter', function(){
        animDisplay();  
    });


   $(".wrapper").on('mouseleave', function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
        $(".first").show();
        $(".second").hide();
   });
```